# kendo treeview not loading after ajax success

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-treeview

I'm trying to load kendo treeview using ajax data source. This is my HTML

```
<div ng-controller="TreeController" style="margin-left:200px;">
    <div kendo-tree-view k-options="treeOptions"
         k-data-source="treeObj" id="ktree"></div>
    <br />
</div>
```

And this is my javascript

```
.success(function (datax) {
            //if (data.length == 0) {
            //    //customerGroupParentNodeCode="NewTree"
            //    $scope.customerGroupParentNode = "NewTree";
            //}
            arr = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < datax.length; i++) {
                arr.push({
                    id: datax[i].Child_Code,
                    text: datax[i].Child_Name,
                    parent: datax[i].Parent_Code
                });
            }
            var startingPoint = loggedLocation + '/ROOT-0';
            arr2 = getNestedChildren(arr, startingPoint);
            alert(getNestedChildren(arr, startingPoint)[0].items[0].id)
            var knobj2 = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                data: arrayObj
            });
            //setting heirarchial data to scope
            $scope.treeObj = knobj2;
        }).error(function (data) {
        });
```

But tree doesn't load with ajax success. When i declare array exactly same as generated array from ajax request kendo tree is generated.

```
    var arrayObj = [{
            id: 2,
            text: "test",
            expanded: true,
            items: [{
                id: 10,
                text: "February.pdf",
                //spriteCssClass: "pdf"
            }, {
                id: 11,
                text: "March.pdf",
                //spriteCssClass: "pdf"
            }, {
                id: 12,
                text: "April.pdf",
                //spriteCssClass: "pdf"
            }]
        }]            
       var knobj = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                data: arr2
            });

        //setting heirarchial data to scope
        $scope.treeObj = knobj;
```

this is working.

Answer (score 0):

you can in the success function add :

`var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
        treeview.setDataSource(data);`

make `setDataSource(dataArray)` initialize treeView